# viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear not called when presenting view controller from Side Menu?

Tags: ios, swift, side-menu

I'm using this library to show a side menu inside my app: https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu

All is fine except for one thing. When I present a `viewcontroller` from the side menu, and then dismiss this view controller to the main view controller, the viewWillAppear and/or viewDidAppear of the main view controller is not called ever.

From SideMenuVC (side menu view controller) I present other view controller:

```
let myPortfoliosNC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "myPortfoliosNC")
present(myPortfoliosNC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Next, form the myPortfolioNC i dismiss (from the first view controller) and when go to main view controller the `viewDidAppear` and `viewWillAppear` is not called. Any idea of what i'm doing wrong ??

Comment: Is the viewDidDissapear from your mainViewController called when you show another viewController?

Comment: @Pat_Morita let me check. One moment please !

Comment: @Pat_Morita not viewDidDissapear called from the side menu !

Comment: If it doesn't disappear it's still visible (probably behind) and so viewWillAppear is not called. You either need to manually dismiss It, check if your library offers methods to do so or work with delegates or notifications to update information between them.

Comment: @Pat_Morita thanks, let me check. BrB !

Comment: The way this pod works is that the views are displaying over the main viewcontroller.
So the main is never dismissed when you go to a new view

Comment: @Len_X so what you suggest i need to do?, i push some view controllers from there and i need to refresh a table view when go again to main view controller !

Comment: I think the solution here is with delegate or notifications (just that @Pat_Morita say) !

Comment: Navigate the viewController instead of present.

Comment: Solved using NotificationCenter, thanks a lot everyone !